# How can I integrate Angular with an existing JavaScript architecture that makes heavy use of clone?

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on a legacy web application (well, I say legacy, it's from about a year ago and programmed in Knockout and JQuery), and I'd like to program a new interface in Angular, with a view to replacing all other portions of the application with Angular as we go on as this is a very complicated user interface that isn't horrible enough to warrant a complete rewrite.

I would like to integrate Angular code with the existing codebase, and for my first controller I'd like to program a pop-up box which allows the user to modify some data. I created a div with a `data-ng-controller` of "MyController" and it all works well, but I don't seem to be able to create many of them.

If we have multiple controllers, i.e:

```
<div data-ng-controller="MyController">
</div>
<div data-ng-controller="MyController">
</div>
```

Both instances of MyController would have their own scope which is definitely want, and it works totally fine for my app this way. But unfortunately, my system works on cloning a div for every instance of the pop-up box:

```
<div data-ng-controller="MyController" id="myWindow">
</div>

<script>
    function showWindow()
    {
        var dialog = $("myWindow").clone();
        dialog.show();
    )
</script>
```

When `showWIndow()` is called, the reference to MyController seems to travel along with it, so I don't get two instance of MyController.

I can't seem to find how to create multiple instances of the same controller and attach it though.

For example, I thought this might work:

```
<div id="myWindow">
</div>

<script>
    function showWindow()
    {
        var dialog = $("myWindow").clone().setupDialog();
        dialog.attr("data-ng-controller", "MyController");
        dialog.show();
    )
</script>
```

But unfortunately, the breakpoint in MyController never gets hit. I suspected that this might be due to the order of attaching,  but reversing the call to attr() and show had no effect:

```
var dialog = $("myWindow").clone().setupDialog();
dialog.show();
dialog.attr("data-ng-controller", "MyController");
```

I assume that there's some method in the angular library somewhere that allows me to instantiate a controller and attach it to an element. About an hour of googling has yielded nothing but I can't believe that something like this doesn't exist somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML must be *compiled* to make angular directives work.

Usually the compile steps are done by angular behind the scenes (ng-app, bootstrap). Ng-repeat does it for example when creating new templates throug iterations.

But here, angularJS doesn't "know" you have DOM nodes to compile and you must do it manually.

You must learn about compile on angular, here are the docs:

- [reference api for $compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) (the last exemple on this page is the one that helped me the most)
- [reference guide for compiling on angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler)

Here's what you might have to do (not sure because I haven't a deep knowledge on this):

- create a scope for your duplicated widget
- compile the template (where angular look dom markup for directives and expressions)
- link the compiled template to the created scope

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found it, but I don't know if this is necessarily the correct way to do it.

I firstly removed the `data-ng-app property` from my `<body>` element. I then applied the `data-ng-controller` programatically and called angular.bootstrap to specify the module I wanted to link to the element:

```
function showWindow()
{
    var dialog = $("myWindow")
        .clone()
        .attr("data-ng-controller", "MyController")
        .setupDialog();

    angular.bootstrap(dialog, ["MyModule"]);

    dialog.show();
)
```

It certainly works for me, although I'm not sure if there are side-effects to doing this that won't be apparent until later.

Comment: bootstrapping should be done once per app. I am not sure what would the consequences be. I think it will mess your rootscope and maybe run() statements.

Comment: Here it works because bootstraping causes the compilation of the HTML of your widget. You can refer to my post to see about compiling.